# SwiftUI: changing @State variable value does not update UI when called from outside

Tags: swiftui

I am using a `SwiftUI` view inside my `UIKit` view controller. In the `SwiftUI` view there is a button with a simple logic to enable / disable its parent section.

I have these state variables:

```
@State private var username: String = ""
@State private var password: String = ""
@State private var isActionCalled = false
```

And in my form I have this section:

```
/// Form
Section {
    Button("Login") {
        isActionCalled = true
        delegate?.login(username: username, password: password)
    }
}
.disabled(username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty || isActionCalled)
///

func setIsActionCalled(value: Bool) {
    isActionCalled = value
}
```

When I click on the button (username and password are not empty) the button will be disabled.

When the hosting view controller calls `setIsActionCalled(false)` form the main queue after the async network call, the function inside the `SwiftUI` view sets the value to `false` but the UI does not change and the button remains disabled.

Am I missing something?

Here is the sample project: https://github.com/maysamsh/update-swiftui-from-uikit

Comment: You aren't showing the call site for `setIsActionCalled(false)`, but in general, you can't imperatively call a function on a SwiftUI view like that from outside, since you can't guarantee that the view is the same instance in the hierarchy. If you include a [mre] it might be easier to give a full diagnosis and possible solution.

Comment: @jnpdx I know that it's the same instance. I'll add the minimal example shortly

Comment: The fact that the `@State` isn't working as expected suggests that even if it is the same instance, it's not tracked by the system correctly with the state/hierarchy system. Perhaps the example will be illuminating, but in the meantime, I'll say that storing your state in an `ObservableObject` (where you hold a firm reference to that object in the parent view) is likely a workable solution.

Comment: @jnpdx I added the sample project

Comment: @jnpdx what you suggested worked. Thanks. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as the solution. I'll update the project on git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SwiftUI, you can't reach into child views and modify their state reliably. Instead, shared state should be owned by the parent view.

Here's a modified version of your code that uses an `ObservableObject` with a reference held by the parent that gets passed down to the child:

```
class SharedState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActionCalled = false
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var sharedState = SharedState()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let swiftUIView = SwiftUIView(sharedState: self.sharedState)

        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        addChild(hostingController)
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @StateObject var sharedState : SharedState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Button("Button 1") {
                        sharedState.isActionCalled = true
                    }
                }.disabled(sharedState.isActionCalled)
                
                Section {
                    Text("Click here to enabled the above button")
                    Button("Click") {
                        setIsActionCalled(value: false)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func setIsActionCalled(value: Bool) {
        sharedState.isActionCalled = value
    }
}
```

Comment: is it not reliable even with a strong reference to`@ObservedObject` value?

Comment: Holding a reference to a `ObservedObject` isn't reaching into the child view's owned state. It should be completely reliable.